# Can't return the first function from Bot.event on_message

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, nested, discord.py

## Code

---

Here's (a little part) of my code:

```
@Bot.command()
async def Spy(ctx, user:Member): #I did from discord import * before
    author = ctx.message.author
    ...
    @Bot.event
    async def on_typing(channel, user, when):
        ... #... means that there's some irrilevant code between two lines, but it's not a pass
    @Bot.event
    async def on_message(mess):
        if mess.author == author:
            if mess.content == "Stop spying!":
                global End
                End = True
        await Bot.process_commands(mess)
    global End
    if End:
        End = False
        return #this returns the whole function/command Spy
```

There's no error raised with my code.

## Problem

`return` makes the Spy command end, but events keep running.

## Question

Do you know how to make all the events (`on_typing` and `on_message` aren't the only ones) end with the return?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never seen anyone put events inside commands, you don't do that, you should use [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) instead.

Comment: I upvoted your comment because you made me discover this wait_for method, which will be usefull. 
Unfortunately it isn't what i need, because once a message is sendt, I need to read it and understand if the Bot has to stop the Spy command or not.
If it happens only once, It won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

---

Maybe I found the answer to my own question:
I have to put `on_message` as the first event in the function, and then use End bool to end all the others.

## Edit

---

As @Łukasz Kwieciński explained me, I should use the `Bot.wait_for()` method.

```
@Bot.command()
async def Spy(ctx, user:Member):
    ...
    while True:
        channel, uSer, when = Bot.wait_for("typing") #Instead of on_typing event
        if uSer == user:
            await ctx.message.author.send(f"{user.mention} is typing in {channel}")
        message = Bot.wait_for("message") #Instead of on_message event
        if message.content == "Stop":
            return
```

Easier and much shorter than my previous solution.